# Using my computer as MySQL database and access with Xamarin.forms app

Tags: wireless-networking, mysql, database, c#

I have developed an app from Xamarin. forms (C#) and I want to use my own computer to host a MySQL database. I have forwarded my port on my router as well but the database can only be accessed when my phone(Xamarin. forms app) and my computer (MySQL database and server) are connected on the same WIFI.

So far I have;

1. create a user in the MySQL database and have given to connect with any address(%) privilege
2. Forwarded port 3306 from my router
3. Check port 3306 on my windows firewall(it is there). The database can be accessed with the local network.
4. Add bind-address = 0.0.0.0 under [mysqlId] in my.ini file.[The my.ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Low1J.png)
5. Bang my head on the wall after trying everything above several times.

[Router Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whvbi.png)

[Connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piEqk.png)

Comment: Where did you get the public IP from?  Is it the info page of your router for its WAN or some whatsmyip site? And if you got it from the former, are you sure that's a public IP? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT#Shared_address_space

Comment: I got it from whatsmyip site

Comment: Then you should check the WAN info page to see if your router's WAN IP is the public IP (i.e. whether it is behind NAT / the public IP is exclusively assigned to you)

Comment: @TomYan from the information from my router. It says my wan Ip is something 192.168.... It is not my public IP address

Comment: Hmm AFAIK it's rare that IP from `192.168.0.0/16` would be used by an ISP for its NAT. Unless you are looking at the wrong place (which is telling you its LAN IP), I suppose this router is connected to another home router? (yours or maybe like your landlord's)

Comment: Yeah, actually I have two routers, mine is connected to another router. So this means I have to port forward from that router too?

Comment: Well it *might* work, but there are chances it won't as well. Either way that's the *least* you need to do.

Comment: @TomYan I have tried port forwarding from the first router to the second and from the second to my computer but still, it is not working...

Comment: This sounds like a CGN issue.  Not what you want to hear, but have you tried setting up a VPN from your Mysql server (to a provider that will sell you a static IP over VPN)?

Comment: Well, I have been trying to use SSH tunneling method instead of port-forwarding now. I think this one will make my life easier. If you guys have some source for connecting xamarin.forms with mysql database through SSH tunneling please let me know. Thank you all for your time.